# Best things, from a Configuration Management perspective, to do in an automated build?

Tags: build-automation, release, release-management

I have a fairly long and complex build automation script. From a configuration management perspective, what are the best practises for an automated build? I saw a thread about cool things to do in an automated build, but what's important?

E.g. backing up and zipping up all the outputted artifacts of the build is one thing and timing the build, what else along these lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mentioned the half of the ans; rest would be streamlining the 
multi-projects, 
enhanceable, 
Build Labels,
Self testing Code,
Timeline,
Scalability,

From my point of view two most important things are time, coverage level.

Hope this helps a little.